# Is there any efficient way to get csv data with SQL in NodeJS

Tags: sql, node.js, csv, unixodbc

I have a large CSV file of 30 million rows.
I want to run SQL queries on it. Like, I want to fetch specific date's data and want to run some aggregation operations.

**Anyone can help me? please**

Comment: It would be much better to load it into some DBMS (MySQL, PostgreSQL for instance) and add some indexes.

Comment: If you have `Notepad++` you can either use the `CsvQuery` plug-in to run queries on the csv text file, or use the `CSV Lint` plug-in to convert the csv to an SQL INSERT script to load it into a database.

Comment: that's okay but is there any way without loading into any DB? like ODBC?